# Checking if value is there before binding it

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have some knockout templates that have values come in from the viewmodel. In some instances the values do not come in because they have not been set yet (the user sets what they want radio buttons to say and so on). In those cases where I'm trying to bind those values it is of course coming back with a typeError.

To fix this I have tried to set a default in the viewModel, but that didn't work at all. I am now trying to see f in knockout I can only run the databinding if the value is there otherwise ignore it.

I have tried wrapping it in a `ko if` statement, but this seemed to fail as well. E.g.:

```html
<!-- ko if: value -->
   <input autocomplete="off" type="text" data-bind="text: value" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

Is there any way to make this work? I really don't fancy redoing all my templates (close to 50 of them).

Comment: What's in that `text` field? Also, is it an `observable`?

Comment: Nothing, it's part of a dropdown that holds options. It just needs that final selected value for it to work. And yes it is.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: It's a typeError saying it can't find the value. This is because it is not set yet which is why I am trying to see if I can detect if that value is there or not before trying to put it in a databind.

Comment: For the HTML you pasted, there's no reason for Knockout to complain, even when `value()` is null.

Comment: But the fact is it is complaining and I need to solve it. That is why I am asking for a correct way to detect of the value is there. This is not working.

Comment: It's impossible to understand why it's complaining from the code you provided. Either create a Fiddle or provide more details.

Comment: I am only looking for a proper way to detect if the value is there or not. I have no other pertinent code to show and to set up an exact environment in a fiddle would be impossible because it would take to long/be way to complicated/ involve revealing a companies code.

Comment: At least paste the full error shown in your console

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined  (the value)

Comment: So, you're using `length` somewhere else in your code. Where is it?

Comment: That is in the knockout.js file. It cannot find the length of a property that is not there yet. I know why I am getting this error, it is because I do not yet have the value that it is trying to bind. That is why I need a correct if statement.

Comment: Have you tried `ko if: $data.value`? This is how you can safely check if the property even exists on your view model.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/5abb8j0n/, `value()` is indeed `undefined` and yet, no errors.

Comment: "I know why I am getting this error, it is because I do not yet have the value that it is trying to bind. That is why I need a correct if statement." I'm not convinced that is the problem, posting more relevant code is necessary.

Comment: why not default value to empty string or use computed

Answer (score 0):

For the approach you're trying currently, you need to coerce the `value` to a boolean using the `!!` idiom (which then also requires you to execute it to get the observable's *value*). In addition, your example uses the `text` binding which doesn't make much sense with an `input` element, use the `value` binding instead. For example:

```js
var vmWithValue = { value: ko.observable('my value') };
var vmWithoutValue = { value: ko.observable(undefined) };

ko.applyBindings({ items: [vmWithValue, vmWithoutValue] });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: items -->
  <!-- ko if: !!value() -->
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" data-bind="value: value" />
  <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```